# 'Countif' combined with 'If'

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, countif

I'm looking to use a set variable as the search criterion for a Countif statement to look for "User 1" in "A:A" in sheet "Unallocated". If the Countif comes back with a value of `0`, I want to skip running code and instead carry on to the next Countif (there aren't any currently but once I get this logic correct I will use it a few times over).

Here is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

Dim iVal As Integer
Dim User As String
'Dim Wkb As Workbook 'to be used later

User = "User 1"
iVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("Unallocated").Range("A2:A"), "User 1")
If iVal = 0 Then GoTo ALabel
Call User1Allo 'macro held in a module
MsgBox ("It Tried to run the macro")
ALabel:
MsgBox ("It Didn't try to run the macro")

'For Each Wkb In Workbooks 'to be used later
'        If Not Wkb.ReadOnly And Windows(Wkb.Name).Visible Then 'to be used later
'            Wkb.Save 'to be used later
'        End If 'to be used later
'    Next 'to be used later


End Sub
```

Comment: Looks fine, though you don't need "Call" anymore, and you could put `User` in the `Countif` function where `"User 1"` is. Are you going to be deploying the same logic against multiple users?

Comment: Hi @puzzlepiece87 I did originally use the "User" in the Countif instead of "User 1" but in a desperate attempt to get the code to work I changed it to the direct text.
I keep getting the dreaded "Run-time error '1004' - Application-defined or object-defined error" for the line of the countif logic, and never know ho to go about fixing it. I was wondering if there was anything silly i'd done/missed that was causing it? Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, do you only get the 1004 with the variable name in there, or also now with the direct text?

Comment: Why do you have A2:A in your countif function? I think that might cause an error.

Comment: @wowdude Did you try qualifying the worksheet with its workbook? Try `iVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Unallocated").Range("A2:A"), User)`

Comment: Ah, quite right @seadoggie01. I have removed this and simply change it to "A:A" which seems to work fine. Thanks! It would seem now, however, that whether or not occurrences of "User 1" are found in column A, the whole of the code is run, ignoring the If statement and "Then GoTo" sections. Any ideas?

Comment: @Wowdude, I think you need an exit sub before your ALabel, otherwise it will run no matter what.

Comment: Hi @seadoggie01 I tried that and it asks me to define "ALabel", which I didn't think was required for a "Then GoTo"?

Comment: I think you may have put an "End Sub" in, it would need to be an "Exit Sub"

Comment: @Wowdude, did you confirm that iVal is ever not 0? Click your cursor next to `If ival = 0` (so it's blinking on that line), push Ctrl-F8, and hover over ival and tell us if it's 0 or not 0.

Comment: Ah there we go. Seems to be running properly. Thanks to the both of you @seadoggie01

Comment: And to @puzzlepiece87 (it wouldn't let m put you both in one comment)

Comment: @puzzlepiece87 Yeah the iVal was giving a 1, and when I removed the "User 1" from column A then the iVal did = 0. Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see from the comments you fixed the `A2:A` syntax. Now in order for the code to truly skip the User1Allo module, I would suggest getting rid of the `GoTo` and the `Call` and just embed everything in a full `If ... Then ... Else` block.

See below:

```
User = "User 1"
iVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("Unallocated").Range("A:A"), User)

If iVal = 0 Then
    MsgBox ("It Didn't try to run the macro")
Else
    User1Allo 'macro held in a module
    MsgBox ("It Tried to run the macro")
End If
```